# How to find that scanf has not got any input

Tags: c

I am trying to find a way to end the program if the user hit enter giving no input the scanf(). I have tried different          methods but nothing worked for me.
I used this code

```
int main()
{
    char line[40];
    while (1)
    {
         scanf("%s",line);
         if (line == NULL)
         {
              break;
          }
     }
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: Given that `line` is an *array* the test `line == NULL` is pointless.

Comment: missing `#include <stdio.h>` in your code

Comment: Replace scanf statement with if(scanf("%s",line)==0)
break;

Answer (score 2):

You probably can't do what you want to with `scanf` alone.

The obvious answer is to look at the return value from `scanf`, since that tells you how many items it successfully matched:

```
while(1) {
    int r = scanf("%s", line);
    if (r < 1) {
          break;
    }

    printf ("you typed %s\n", line);
}
```

But since `scanf`'s `%s` format skips over leading whitespace, and since the newline `\n` is whitespace, `scanf` will sail happily over blank lines until it finds a non-blank character to return.

You might be able to use the `%[]` format with `scanf`.  This matches a *character class*: either certain characters, or (with `^`) everything except certain characters.  You could use it like this:

```
while (1) {
    int r = scanf("%[^\n]", line);
    if (r < 1) {
          break;
    }

    printf ("you typed %s\n", line);

    getchar();    /* over the \n */
}
```

Since you're telling `scanf` to read everything *except* the `\n`, you have to do something else -- here a bare `getchar` call -- to get over the `\n` so you can read the next line.

But if you want to read lines, usually it's cleaner and easier overall to use `fgets` instead:

```
while(1) {
    if(fgets(line, 40, stdin) == NULL) {
          break;
    }

    printf ("you typed %s\n", line);
}
```

(With `fgets` you do have the additional complication that the terminating `\n` character comes back from `fgets` in your `line` array, so depending on what you're doing later, you may have to take steps to delete it.)

Answer (score 1):

Did you read the documentation of [scanf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf)? It returns a scanned item count that you should test.

Before the `scanf`, you should considering clearing your `line` with a `memset(line, 0, sizeof(line))`.

And you can't compare strings with `==` (this tests for address equality). You could use [strcmp](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcmp) (but not with `NULL`, but perhaps with an empty string `""`).

Also, your question could be operating system specific. Since the notion of terminal is OS specific (see e.g. [the tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/) for a Unix point of view). The C11 standard [n1570](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) does not know or care about terminal or <kbd>enter</kbd> keys. And [standard streams](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams) (e.g. `stdin` read by `scanf`) might not be terminals (think of [redirections](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redirection_(computing)) or [pipelines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(computing))), so your question does not have any sense in general.

Of course you should read the documentation of [standard IO](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io) functions, compile your code with all warnings and debug info (so `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)) then [use the `gdb` debugger](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/) to understand the behavior of your program.

You could (and probably should) use [fgets](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) (but don't forget to test its result against failure). If your system have them, you might consider using [getline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html) or even [readline(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html).